# Recording a live video stream in C#/XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio, directx, xna

I have a project that renders the web cam stream onto a texture. I was wondering if there was a way, either through DirectX's Audio/Video functionality or through XNA directly where I can record the stream into an avi file format? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Wait... you want to go webcam -> XNA -> .avi file? Why not just go webcam -> .avi file?

Comment: If possible I would like to also see what's being rendered onto the screen as well as have an .avi file.

Comment: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/45450/338718.aspx
working example of just showing webcam data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct show will do exactly what you need through the ICaptureGraphBuilder

For a C# wrapper, see:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/

Answer (score 0):

I have used this [VideoTexture Class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/VidTextureClassWebcamApp.aspx) before with success and would recommend you to use it. It gives you the current state as `Texture2D`, which is easily renderable and should be reasonable to convert to an avi. If you are using Windows Vista or 7 you need to replace the DirectShowNet.dll with newest one from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/).