# How to create an application for receiving a video stream from a (WiFi) camera?

Tags: c++, video, camera, stream, wifi

I am kind of a beginner in programming, learning it in school, so I really don't know much.

But I want to make a program for PC and maybe app for iPhone/Android that receives a video-stream from a camera and displays it, nothing more.

How do I do this in C++/C# in Visual Studio?

Camera -> WiFi -> PC/Phone

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried Googling/researching this? SO questions should have a clear problem statement and question. This is a very broad question. Also a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679357/recording-a-live-video-stream-in-c-xna

Comment: I have checked on youtube and google but didn't find what I was looking for, your link isn't quite what I had in mind either.

Answer (score 1):

A good library for working with images/video in c++ is OpenCV. I would recommend taking a look at their examples.

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/index.html

Check out the highgui module!

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should first check for cameras that come with a programming API so that it is easy to write programs to communicate with it.
2. If the camera drivers can make it communicate with standard chat apps like Sykpe, you should be able to use C++ and OpenCV to capture a stream from it. But you can choose the language and tools according to what you want to do with the video stream.

Comment: You can also check "Pure Data", a visual programming language that is easy to work with for beginners.